# Kickstart configurations -- ignoredisk and bootloader usage

Tags: linux, centos, rhel

From the Red Hat website,

I found the following link ( Red Hat website ) shows the expression to ignoredisk.

[ignoredisk_option](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html)

From my understanding,

if i set this option to

```
ignoredisk --only-use=sda
```

The image will be deployed and installed on to the sda drive on the client host.

1.If I expect to have this image to be installed on the **sdb**, then I just changed ***sda*** to ***sdb***, is this correct ?

2.

```
bootloader --append=" crashkernel=auto" --location=mbr --boot-drive=sdb
```

For the bootload boot-drive, I should also change it to ***sdb*** if I expect the system to be installed onto ***sdb***, is this correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [kickstart_doc](https://github.com/rhinstaller/pykickstart/blob/master/docs/kickstart-docs.rst) gave me a pretty nice hint.

I finally figured out the usage of my question by going through this document.